# Escape Dollar $ sign in Azure ARM Template Variable

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM Template to deploy a WebApp in Azure. I also have a AppSettings configuration in WebApp (which is used for sending emails) "EmailPassword" to be  deployed along with the ARM Template.

The actual value for variable "EmailPassword" is"Test$am123" in ARM Template.

But when I execute the ARM Template during deployment, the value is stored as "Test123" in the AppSettings of the created WebApp.

I hope this happens because of the $ (dollar) sign in the variable.

How to escape the Dollar sign in the ARM Template variables

**Update**: With the help of 4c74356b41, I found the Issue is not with ARM Template and its Parameters.Json. Instead, I am using the [VSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-ci-in-vsts#set-up-continuous-deployment-in-vs-team-services) Deployment and trying to pass the values to Parameters from the Environment Variables. I overriding the Parameters.json using the "Override Template Parameters" input in VSO.

The Issue is with VSO and it removes the "$am" characters while passing the values to the ARM Deployment.

Comment: So `"Test@am123"` turns into `"Test123"`?...what `$` dollar sign?

Comment: Sorry. Edited the Original Post. The value is "Test$am123" and not "Test@am123"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that escaping is done using `\` character.

update: for me $ doesnt need escaping.

Comment: That's unlikely here.

Comment: why not, it works like that in mine template...I didn't try escaping $ thou

Comment: In an ARM template?

Comment: As the deployment is to be done by some support people, I can't ask people to escape the values when entering the original password. Is there a way to get the original value when reading the variable?

Comment: yes, Robert, in an ARM template. but I've just tested, and for me the $ doesn't need to be escaped... @samjayander not that I know of.

Comment: Yes. But using the \ escape character in value as like "Test\$am123" results in "Test\123".  Btw, I am using VSO Build and am overriding the ARM Template variables using "Override Template Parameters" as shown in the last step of [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-ci-in-vsts#set-up-continuous-deployment-in-vs-team-services)

Comment: yes, you need to escape ``\`` using``\\`` that holds

Comment: I need the $am in middle which is missing the final AppSettings section.

Comment: so whats the problem? for me Test$am123 doesnt get crippled in the template

Comment: The actual problem is the value for AppSettings in ARM Template "Test$am123"  is filled as "Test123" in the WebApp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128177/discussion-between-4c74356b41-and-samjayander).

Comment: can you get into chat with me, i've just tested exactly this, and it worked just fine